# Cannot convert value of type 'mainImage.type' to exprected argument type 'String'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile

How can I pass data in `uicollectionview` and anther images view single images?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as? SelectAnimalViewCell {
        let Category = DataService.instance.getCategories()[indexPath.row]
        cell.updataView(selecting: Category)
        return cell
    } 
    else
    {
        return SelectAnimalViewCell()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let category = DataService.instance.getCategories()[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "PuzzlingVC", sender: category)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let puzzlingVC = segue.destination as? PuzzlingViewController {
        assert(sender as? Selecting != nil)
        puzzlingVC.initPuzzles(category: sender as! Selecting)

    }

    if let puzzleIngController = segue.destination as? PuzzlingViewController{
        assert(sender as? mainImage != nil)
        puzzleIngController.meanImageView = mainImage.init(mainImagePuzzle: mainImage)
        //cannot convert value of type 'mainImage.type' to exprected argument type 'Strign'
    }

//        let DestViewController : PuzzlingViewController = segue.destination as! PuzzlingViewController
//        DestViewController.mainImage = DataService.instance.getCategories(Selecting.init(imageName: "", mainImageName: mainImage))
}
```

Comment: Please, edit your question. Make the code readable and add the code where your mainImage class is created